# Why does Rachel Parsons torture Miranda instead of the real perpetrator?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, gothika

In *Gothika*, why does Rachel Parsons torture the innocent patient Miranda instead of her rapist, Sheriff Ryan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](http://gothika.wikia.com/wiki/Rachel_Parsons) she cannot affect her rapists in any way, but Miranda is prone to her influence.

> Upon her escape she fled to the river bridge and plunged herself to
>   its depths. Her angry spirit however continues to haunt the only
>   person that can see her ghost, Doug's wife, Miranda.

The ghost of the boy that Miranda sees at the end seems to confirm that she has a "gift".